Appending a line in place with sed on macOS
The sed command below works on Linux (without the '') to append a line in place in a file, but I can't get it to work on macOS with its sed command:
$ sed -i '' "/my_integration_tenants:/a \    - $M_TENANT_ID" ./helm/some-service/values.yaml
sed: 1: "/my_integration_ ...": extra characters after \ at the end of a command

I've tried with 1, 2, 3, and 4 backslashes but they all give the same error.
What's the correct command to append a line in place in a file with sed on macOS?

In some versions of sed (that are common on Macs), you need a literal newline after the backslash for the a command.

You might try sed -e $'/my...:/a\\\n   - '"$M_TENANT_ID" ...

No luck with that.  It gives the same error.

Try this :
sed -i '' "/my_integration_tenants:/a\\
    - $M_TENANT_ID
" ./helm/some-service/values.yaml


That works, but it does not put the new text on its own line.  I've also tried with - $M_TENANT_ID\\\\n but it won't add a newline.

Have you tried my update, with the closing " on the next line ?

Try using just one backslash char at end of line. (This is what I expected to work). When I use two backslashes I get an error.

The problem was the /a option.  A colleague of mine suggested using the -e option instead and it works on Linux and MacOS
sed -i '' -e "s/my_integration_tenants:/my_integration_tenants:\n    - $M_TENANT_ID/" ./helm/some-service/values.yaml

The -i '' prevents making a backup of the values.yaml file.  If you use -i without the empty single quotes you get a backup file.

I found that on Suse I had to remove the empty quotes ''

The empty quotes (-i '') is required  (used to be?)  for the std version of sed installed with the MacOSes. If you've installed and are using the the gnu-sed option on Mac, the -i '' isn't required.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -i '' '/my_integration_tenants:/G;//s/.$/& - '"$M_TENANT_ID"'/' file

Match the place where the line is to be appended.
Append a newline (the G command appends a newline and an empty hold space).
Replace the newline with itself and the added content.
